# Как блокировать подсказку от android

Tags: android, файлы, android-intent

Для чтения fb2 файлов я использую свою активити и парсинг, но каждый раз при выбора файла, система предлагает программы по умолчанию. Подскажите пжлста, как выключить это программно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привожу участок кода, в котором: после нажатия на кнопку открывается pickerLoader, а после выбора файла, в ResultActivity открывается файл. Всю логику приводить не буду.

```
private fun launchPicker() {

    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
    val mimeTypes = arrayOf("text/xml", "application/pdf")
    intent.type = "*/*"
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        //alert user that file manager not working
        Toast.makeText(this,"Ошибка выбора файла", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)
    if (intent != null && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            val uri = intent.data
            fileName = getFileName(uri!!)
            filePath = PathUtil.getPath(this, uri)

            val tempBook = Book(binding.bookName.text.toString(),
                    filePath)


            if(tempBook.getType() == "pdf") {
                val intentNew = Intent(this, BookReaderActivity::class.java)
                intentNew.putExtra(BOOK, tempBook)
                intentNew.putExtra(CREATE_MODE, true)
                startActivityForResult(intentNew, IS_CREATE_MODE_REQUEST)
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_animation_enter, R.anim.right_animation_leave)

            } else if(tempBook.getType() == "fb2") {
                val intentNew = Intent(this, BookDisplayActivity::class.java)
                intentNew.putExtra(CREATE_MODE, true)
                startActivityForResult(intentNew, IS_CREATE_MODE_REQUEST)
                val options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(this, R.anim.right_animation_enter, R.anim.right_animation_leave)
                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
            }



        }else if(requestCode == IS_CREATE_MODE_REQUEST){

            val tempBook = intent.getParcelableExtra<Book>(BOOK)

            if(tempBook.getCountPages() != 0){
                binding.fileName.text = fileName
                binding.countPage.setText(tempBook.getCountPages().toString())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: можно использовать [простой файл-селектор](https://github.com/MostafaNasiri/AndroidFileChooser), чтобы пользователь сам выбрал нужный файл и затем самому загрузить его по полученному пути. Другие [варианты библиотек](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=android+file+chooser&type=)

Comment: именно так я и делаю. Но уже после того как пользователь выбирает файл, запускается моя активти, а система предлагает свои варианты. Там на фоне видно, что прогружается читалка. Мб у меня ошибка при выборе файла? Из дома приведу пример используемого кода, сейчас на работе

Comment: Как вы запускаете свою активити? Используйте явный интент, тогда никакого выбора предлагаться не будет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полностью выключить никак. Это прерогатива пользователя.

Можно только минимизировать этот список, правильно настроив MIME тип в интенте, который посылаете системе для выбора файла.

Но если на этот же MIME зарегистрировано другое приложение, вы от него не избавитесь, только пользователь.

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем, проблема решается просто. Нужно открывать активити с чтением файла не так:

```
            val intentNew = Intent(this, BookDisplayActivity::class.java)
            intentNew.putExtra(CREATE_MODE, true)
            startActivityForResult(intentNew, IS_CREATE_MODE_REQUEST)
            val options = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(this, R.anim.right_animation_enter, R.anim.right_animation_leave)
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
```

А вот так:

```
                val intentNew = Intent(this, BookDisplayActivity::class.java)
                intentNew.putExtra(CREATE_MODE, true)
                startActivityForResult(intentNew, IS_CREATE_MODE_REQUEST)
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_animation_enter, R.anim.right_animation_leave)
```

И будет счастье) Возможно, при использовании опций, передаются какие-то дополнительные параметры, которые дергают системные ниточки и вызвают подсказку с выбором файла. Спасибо всем кто принял участие в обсуждении!

Comment: Потому что `startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())` в вашем коде было вообще непонятно зачем? Никакой магии и никакие опции тут ни при чем.

Comment: я возможно ошибаюсь, но разве анимация не была запаковано в опции?

Comment: Была, но зачем запускать интент, который вам прислала система после выбора файла с этой анимацией?

Comment: Так это описка! Я вот только заметил! Перед вызовом функции я создаю новый интент для запуска нового активити, но по ошибки написал интент filepicker-а. Там должен быть intentNew

Comment: Так в этой описке и есть вся проблема. Это и пытаюсь вам донести.

Comment: в таком случае следовало просто сказать: "у вас отличаются названия intent"

Comment: Так они же не просто отличаются, вы их еще и два раза запускаете! Я же не ясновидящий чтобы понять что там у вас за задумка по куску кода :)